# A simple sql query Need explanation how is it giving output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I got this query from some one and I queried this in SQL Server 2012

```
Select 20 | 25 as test
```

O/P : 29

```
select 20 & 25 as test
```

O/P : 16

```
select 10 | 25 as test
```

O/P : 27

```
select 10 & 25 as test
```

O/P : 8

I need step by step explanation for this output, can any one help me out.

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server 2008, or SQL Server 2012? Choose.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [Bitwise Operators (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: In Binary, 20 is 10100 and 25 is 11001
When OR (pipe symbol) is applied on it, it gives, 11101 which is 29 ....You can study more at http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_or.html

Comment: @GouthamM . . . If you don't understand the bitwise operators, don't use them.  They are only needed under very special circumstances -- I don't think I've ever needed to use bitwise operators for real applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unlike `binary calculators` SQL Server `does not add` values if the
   operator is OR, it uses `pipe character` (|) for bitwise OR
   operator.  It returns 1 if one or both bits are 1
2. AND returns `1` if both bits are `1`. Either of the bit is `0` it returns `0`

**Step by Step Explanation as you were looking for**

> **Select 20 | 25 as test** <-- we will do it for this one first

First it will convert these values to Binary i.e

1. **20 = 10100**
2. **25 = 11001**

Now it returns 1 if one or both bits are 1 else it returns 0.

Considering this the result is **11101** which is **29**

> **select 20 & 25 as test**  <-- Lets have a look into this now

Convert to Binary -

1. **20 = 10100**
2. **25 = 11001**

& returns 1 if both bits are 1 else returns 0

According to this the result is **10000** which is **16**